# addSubLayer to UIView instead of root view

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer

When I draw a graph and add it to the controller's view, the graph is displayed correctly.

```
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
self.currentGraph = shapeLayer;
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0;
//[self.graphView.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer]; // Doesn't work!
[self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer]; // Works!
```

If I add it to the UIView that should contain the graph, the graph is not displayed at all.

What might be causing the problem?

Comment: Any general advice on how to debug this problem will be appreciated as much as the solution to the problem!

Comment: One idea is to confirm that graphView (with or without the additional layer) is visible.  Maybe set its background color to something bright and make sure its visible.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a custom `UIView` subclass to contain your layer.  That way you get all the benefits of being a UIView, but with the flexibility of having control of the type of layer.

```
class UIGradientView: UIView {

    override class func layerClass() -> AnyClass {
        return CAShapeLayer.self
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! but in this case, `graphView` is also a UIView that should contain the graph as its sublayer so I don't know what's the difference

Comment: @MaximusS This allows you to manage the hierarchy by using `addSubview` instead of `addSublayer`.  That also means that you can more easily debug into it and see where the view is, set a background color, and figure out what the placement issue is.